# Jenkins pipeline: prevent a job from failing if upstream jobs do not exist

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins I have a Groovy pipeline script which triggers multiple jobs afterward:

```
 stage('Build other pipelines') {

        steps {
            build job: "customer-1/${URLEncoder.encode(BRANCH_NAME, "UTF-8")}", propagate: true, wait: false
            build job: "customer-2/${URLEncoder.encode(BRANCH_NAME, "UTF-8")}", propagate: true, wait: false
            build job: "customer-3/${URLEncoder.encode(BRANCH_NAME, "UTF-8")}", propagate: true, wait: false
        }
    }
```

Now, I develop on a feature-branch e.g. `feature/ISSUE-123` just for customer 2, so the jobs `customer-1/ISSUE-123` and `customer-3/ISSUE-123` do not exist. How can I tell Jenkins not to fail in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider extracting a new method called `safeTriggerJob` that wraps the `build` step with the try-catch block that catches exception thus let the pipeline continue running.

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
         stage("Test") {
             steps {
                 safeTriggerJob job: "job2", propagate: true, wait: false
             }
         }
    }
}

void safeTriggerJob(Map params) {
    try {
        build(params)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        echo "WARNING: ${e.message}"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline (hide)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /home/wololock/.jenkins/workspace/sandbox-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] build
[Pipeline] echo
WARNING: No item named job2 found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Alternatively, instead of extracting a dedicated method you could add try-catch directly inside `steps` block, but in this case, you would need to wrap it with `script`, something like:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
         stage("Test") {
             steps {
                 script {
                     try {
                         build job: "job2", propagate: true, wait: false
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         echo "WARNING: ${e.message}"
                     } 

                     // The next build inside its own try-catch here, etc.                        
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```